# Execute Update from table info

Tags: java, mysql

Good Day! I have this Sample Output:

[image]

The left table is my item in my database and the right table would be a table for viewing what items are to be purchased. Clicking Bill out should update the database quantity based on all inputs on the view table (right table).

Here is my code and I'm not sure what to put on my prepared statement for it to get all inputs from the view

```
        String sql="update medinfo set quantity=quantity-? where medID=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = connMed.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, ));
        ps.setString(2, );
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Thanks!

Comment: can i know at right hand side there are 2-column for Quantity ? which is for what ?

Comment: 1 column for quantity from database stocks and 1 for quantity which would be bought (one to be minus)

Comment: please refer my asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Do something likewise,

```
String sql="update medinfo set quantity=? where medID=?";
PreparedStatement ps = connMed.prepareStatement(sql);

Integer updateNetQuantity = Integer.parseInt(get-Quantity-on-Hand)) - Integer.parseInt(get-Quantity-to-purchased)); // here , in your case it's 995-3 = 992

Integer medID= getCurrentItem's MedID; // here , in your case it will be 22/21/20...etc

ps.setInt(1, updateNetQuantity );
ps.setString(2, medID);
ps.executeUpdate();
```